# How to use Heading Style while automating word in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

My program is copying string from other file and it should convert as heading while pasting in word. (MS 2007). I tried recording macro:

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2").
```

But how to do it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what I did:

```
object headingType = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2;
wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.set_Style(ref headingType);
```